# finding convergence of this series

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I have to show that this series:

$\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ on any closed interval that dosnt contain an integer.

converges uniformly and absolutely.

I know that $\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ $\le$ $\frac{1}{n^2C}$ and how to show that it converges uniformly/absolutely from the M-test and the p-test.

I am having trouble though with how it was found that $\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ $\le$ $\frac{1}{n^2C}$

Could someone people help me understand how this was found to be the case?

Comment: I think it should be $$\frac{1}{n^2-C^2}$$ instead of $$\frac{1}{n^2C}.$$

Comment: That is what I orignally thought but my professor said it wasn't that. I also realized I had the wrong interval on there.

Answer (score 3):

For large enough $n$,  we have

$$0\leq x\leq C \implies$$
$$ n^2-C^2\leq n^2-x^2 \leq n^2$$

$$\implies  0<\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2-C^2}$$

but
$$\frac{1}{n^2-C^2}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\;(n\to+\infty)$$

thus

$\sum\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ is normally and uniformly convergent at $[0,C]$.

Comment: does this change if the interval is: on any closed interval that dosnt contain an integer

Comment: @Sarahmarie It is true for any $C>0$.